# Pass array from template to partial

Tags: templates, typo3, partial, fluid, typo3-6.1.x

My showAction() looks like this:

```
public function showAction() {
        $form = $this->formRepository->findByUid($this->settings['form']);
        $arguments = $this->request->getArguments();
        $this->view->assignMultiple(
            array(
                'form' => $form,
                'arguments' => $arguments
            )
        );
    }
```

In the template of this action I try to give 'arguments' to all my partials:

```
<f:render partial="FormElement/{formElement.type}" arguments="{formElement:formElement, arguments:arguments}" />
```

The debug of {arguments} in the template shows me that everything is fine. If I debug the {arguments} inside the partials, it returns NULL. Even if I give all arguments to the partials (arguments="{_all}"), NULL will be returned by debugging {arguments} inside the partials.

Everything else works fine!

Comment: I've created an action and a template with a partial and could not reproduce the problem. What if you assign 'arguments' with just a simple string instead of $this->request->getArguments(). Do the string pass through to the partial? Have you tried to rename your variable 'arguments' to something else like 'myargs'?

Comment: Inside the assignMultiple() I changed it like this: 'humpa' => 'WHATS WRONG?'. Also changed the 'arguments' against 'humpa' by giving the partials their arguments (arguments="{formElement:formElement, humpa:humpa}"). The debug of {humpa} inside the partial returned NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me. You might want to check your php.ini file for the following setting "max_input_nesting_level". Sometimes, if this parameter is set to a low value and your handling a complex object you run into this restriction. You might want to change it to 128 oder even 256. (Don't forget to restart your apache after changing your php.ini)

Comment: Impossible to change the value (current is 64). I work on a managed server. But also giving a string instead of the arguments-array gave me NULL.

Comment: So I've learned I can change the value via .htaccess... I changed it to the value of 256 (checked it via phpinfo()) but sadly that was not the answer.